# Is it currently "safe" to use arrows from htmlentities instead of arrow images?

Tags: xhtml, fonts, character-encoding, cross-browser, html

In the real world, are there any issues with using the htmlentities in Grade A browsers for → right and ← left arrows per [this link](http://www.elizabethcastro.com/html/extras/entities.html#shapes)? Can everyone reading this page see these arrows ↔ ?

Apparently if the character is not in your font set, they won't appear, but so far my work has been to english speaking audiences...don't the arrows come standard for vast majority of font sets in English? I'm talking about the standard fonts used...I rarely set my CSS to fonts other than Verdana, Arial and the like designed for on screen use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Apparently if the character is not in your font set, they won't appear

Your font set can be pretty inclusive. I read the [font matching algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#algorithm) as saying that if a given character isn't found in one font, then the browser will look for that character in the next font.

In particular, although I may be wrong, I'd kind of expect the generic fonts like "serif" and "sans-serif" to support the standard entities; and so I'd guess you're safe if you include a generic font at the end of your font set.